# Display all images without category in JoomGallery

Tags: php, joomla

I am using JoomGallery but  i want to display all images instead of creating categories first and then place images in categories in this way only categories are being displayed on landing page .I want all images to be displayed landing page . I have searched a lot for it

Comment: can you not simply create 1 category, and set the menu item to that specific category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create one Category, and add all your images to that category.

After that, disable category view - you can do it using the menu just to point to the directly to your category view index.php?view=category&catid=1&option=com_joomgallery;

or you can do it by overriding the template. In this case:

create a directory in your html directory in your template directory (templates/yourtemplate/html/) and name it com_joomgallery, then, inside create a directory named "category" and place inside the files you'll find in  components/com_joomgallery/views/category/tmpl/

The default_images.php that you'll find there, is the one that renders the thumbnails that will further link each one to the detail view.